# Java WebSocket client with Spring integration (DI) and no 'CONNECT' message

Tags: java, websocket, client, spring-websocket

I would like to create a java 8 WebSocket client application, that integrates with Spring and sends no initial connect message or the message can be customized.

I have already tried it with tyrus 1.17, but `ClientManager.createClient()` creates new instances of my annotated classes `@ClientEndpoint` and I found no way to use the other instance that Spring created.

I have also tried it with spring-websocket 5.2.9.RELEASE and spring-stomp 5.3.2.RELEASE, but it sends its pre-defined 'CONNECT' message that breaks my integration with the server as it does not understand it.

If someone could help with any guidance on either some examples from google, that I have not seen previously, or with implementations/examples that supports all of it, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jetty-websocket-client-api supports both.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.32.v20200930</version>
</dependency>
```

Add `@org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket` annotation to the spring bean then create four annotated methods to handle the different events:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;

@OnWebSocketConnect public void onConnect(Session session) { }
@OnWebSocketMessage public void onMessage(String text) { }
@OnWebSocketClose public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) { }
@OnWebSocketError public void onError(Throwable cause) { }
```

Then wire up the WebSocket client and connect

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;

@Override
public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
    Object mySpringBeanForWebsocket = this;
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
    client.start();
    client.connect(mySpringBeanForWebsocket, new URI("wss://my.secure.websocket.server.address.com"), request);
}
```

Then the custom initial message can be sent as soon as the api calls the onConnect method

```
@OnWebSocketConnect
public void onConnect(Session session) {
    session.getRemote().sendString("Here comes my first message");
}
```